# Using XML file content loaded via Ajax outside of success call

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

I have this code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "lang_files/" + window.localStorage.language + ".xml",
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(data) {
        var xml_node = $("resources", data);
        $("#index_intro").text(xml_node.find('string[name="index_intro"]').text());
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log("Error loading XML data");
    }
});
```

It works fine, the .text() is set properly using the information from my XML file, I now want to be able to use the XML file across my application, and not just inside the success call, so I did:

```
var xml_node;

$.ajax({
    url: "lang_files/" + window.localStorage.language + ".xml",
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(data) {
        xml_node = $("resources", data);
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log("Error loading XML data");
    }
});

$("#index_intro").text(xml_node.find('string[name="index_intro"]').text());
```

This is not working though, I would like to understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because ajax is asynchronous so at time you call xml_node, it is still undefined. Try this instead:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "lang_files/" + window.localStorage.language + ".xml",
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(data) {
        setIndexIntro($("resources", data));
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log("Error loading XML data");
    }
});

function setIndexIntro(xml_node)
{
   $("#index_intro").text(xml_node.find('string[name="index_intro"]').text());
}
```

Comment: I see, thanks for the information. This works great, have to explores better ways to use this data all across my application now (indexintro is destined for only one page).